# android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

The microhonePopUp method will work in MainActivity, but I'd like for it to work from another class (MediaButtonIntentReceiver).  The problem is with startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); - but I don't know how to resolve it.

in the MainActivity class

```
public void microphonePopUp(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice your answer");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

in the MediaButtonIntentReceiver class

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK == event.getKeyCode()) {
                MainActivity test = new MainActivity(); 
                test.microphonePopUp();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> 12-09 11:20:14.803 19556-19556/com.timtennyson.priceaddition
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.timtennyson.priceaddition, PID: 19556
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.timtennyson.priceaddition.MediaButtonIntentReceiver:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3641)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
>   android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.timtennyson.priceaddition.MainActivity.microphonePopUp(MainActivity.java:103)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.timtennyson.priceaddition.MediaButtonIntentReceiver.onReceive(MediaButtonIntentReceiver.java:27)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3634)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:221) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** create an instance of an activity, service, or provider yourself.

If your objective is to listen for `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcasts while `MainActivity` is visible:

- Move `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` to be a nested class inside of `MainActivity`
- Get rid of `test` from `onReceive()`, and just call `microphonePopUp()` (which I assume is a method on `MainActivity`)
- Register your `MediaButtonIntentReceiver` using `registerReceiver()` in `onStart()` of `MainActivity`, and use `unregisterReceiver()` in `onStop()`

If your objective is to listen `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcasts at other points in time — by registering your receiver in the manifest — while you can do that, you cannot use `microphonePopUp()` from that receiver.

Comment: If MediaButtonIntentReveiver cannot use a method in MainActivity, Is there a way to set a flag from MediaButtonIntentReceiver to MainActivity for MainActivity to use the method MicrophonePopUp?

Comment: @timmyt123: If your objective is to listen for `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcasts while `MainActivity` is visible, you are welcome to use an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`) to have the receiver tell the activity to do something. However, you would still need to use `registerReceiver()`/`unregisterReceiver()`. If your objective is to listen to `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` broadcasts at other times, there may be no `MainActivity` instance for you to work with.

Comment: I have a button to use the microphonePopUp, but I also want the media button to also be able to trigger the microphonePopUp.  Yes, I do have a register receiver  in OnResume() and unregister receiver in OnPause().

Comment: @timmyt123: Personally, I would use the approach outlined in the answer. If this receiver is *only* for use within the activity, the receiver ought to be *defined* in the activity, IMHO. The event bus approach, though, could work.

Comment: Yes, I tried that approach and the media button stopped working, but in the AndroidManifest, I needed to also insert the .MainActivity$MediaButtonIntentReceiver.  It still didn't work and it was suggested to make the MediaButtonIntentReceiver class static and then it wanted StartActivityForResult static.  Changing one class to Static seemed to give me a chain of problems.  I'm going to try the second approach now.  Thank you for your continuous help.

Comment: @timmyt123: If you are using `registerReceiver()` and `unregisterReceiver()`, your receiver should not *be* in the manifest.

Comment: Yes, I have them in the MainActivity.  Everything worked until I tried to get a microphone to pop up after pressing the media button.  I could get a log message when I pressed the media button, but the microphone popping up was a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130318/discussion-between-timmyt123-and-commonsware).